# A way to reference the ID in a multi insert transaction? (postgres)

Tags: postgresql

Assuming table "entity.eid" is auto incrementing, I want to be able to reference the autoincrement value assigned later in the same transaction. The way I have been doing this is by doing multiple transactions which I think is not optimal.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO entity ...;
INSERT INTO t2 (eid, ...) VALUES (?NEW EID REF HERE?, ...), (...), (...);
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are different ways to do this.

The easiest way is to use the `lastval()` function which will return the value generated by the "last" sequence nextval.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO entity ...;
INSERT INTO t2 (eid, ...) VALUES (lastval(), ...), (...), (...);
COMMIT;
```

If you know the name of the sequence for the `entity` table you could also use the `currval` function:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO entity ...;
INSERT INTO t2 (eid, ...) VALUES (currval('entity_eid_seq'), ...), (...), (...);
COMMIT;
```

This can be written in  a more general way by using the `pg_get_serial_sequence()` function, avoiding to hardcode the sequence name:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO entity ...;
INSERT INTO t2 (eid, ...) VALUES (currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('entity', 'eid')), ...), (...);
COMMIT;
```

For more details, please see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html

Answer (score 7):

You don't specify your Postgresql version, but if you are using 8.4+ you can use the `RETURNING` clause to return the id (or any column) that just got inserted.

Docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html

Example:

`INSERT INTO t2 (eid, ...) VALUES (...) RETURNING eid;`

If you are using Postgresql version 9.1+ you can also use `WITH` clauses (aka `Common Table Expressions`) to do the insert into one clause, then reference the values from the `RETURNING` clause to perform more actions (the WITH clauses can chain together).

Docs on `WITH` clause: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that [SERIAL in Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) is just an INT with a [SEQUENCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) as the default value, you could easily query the sequencer yourself in a transaction instead of inserting into the table allowing the default to happen.